# Unique table from multiple ones having same and different columns (SQL)

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I have multiple datasets having different rows and fields.

```
dataset1
Customer_ID   Date       Category Address         City          School
4154124       1/2/2021      A      balboa st.    Canterbury   Middleton
2145124       1/2/2012      A      somewhere     world        St. Augustine
1621573       1/2/2012      A      my_street     somewhere    St. Augustine



dataset2
Customer_ID   Date           Category Country  Zipcode   
14123         12/12/2020        B       UK      EW
416412        14/12/2020        B       ES      


dataset3
Customer_ID   Date          Category School         University 
4124123       07/12/2020       C       Middleton      Oxford
```

I would like a final dataset which includes all the columns (keeping only one copy of the common ones):

```
Customer_ID   Date       Category Address         City          School  Country  Zipcode  University
    4154124       1/2/2021      A      balboa st.    Canterbury   Middleton
    2145124       1/2/2012      A      somewhere     world        St. Augustine
    1621573       1/2/2012      A      my_street     somewhere    St. Augustine
    14123         12/12/2020        B                                    UK      EW
    416412        14/12/2020        B                                    ES      
    4124123       07/12/2020       C                            Middleton                   Oxford
```

would a left join be the best way to get the expected output? How I can keep Customer_ID Date and Category and duplicates column (e.g., School) only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using UNION ALL.

```
SELECT Customer_ID, Date, Category, Address, City, School, '' AS Country, '' AS ZipCode, '' AS university  FROM dataset1 
UNION ALL
SELECT Customer_ID, Date, Category, '', '', '', Country, Zipcode, ''   FROM dataset2
UNION ALL
SELECT Customer_ID, Date, Category, '', '', School, '', '', University FROM dataset3
```

Comment: Not clear which database you are querying on the back end.. If it's Teradata (Vantage) then you should explicitly CAST values (at least the constants) in the first SELECT to have the data type and size needed to hold the final result. Some other databases may default or automatically adjust the result type for each column, but Teradata does not.